# Customers randomly get The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-login

To be clear this is random CUSTOMERS locked out, not ADMIN. Most posts on this are about admin lockouts.

Customers have working accounts (some for years) and have been able to place orders in the past. They go to place a new order, login and are met with "*The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily*". They reset their password (successfully) but still get the same failure when they try logging in with the new password. They try in a different browser and get the same. Admin check and their accounts are **Unlocked**.

This is only affecting a very small number of customers across multiple Magento 2.4 instances and it doesn't appear to matter what browser they are using. We've tested account lockout behaviours (set to 10 mins after 10 failed logins) and that works fine. Account is locked after 10 failed logins and unlocks 10 mins later. So it's not ongoing account hacking causing this.

As we can't reproduce and don't have access to individual customer devices experiencing this random lockout we have no idea why it happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe this is a known issue. Cookie domain caused the issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13505

Comment: Thanks. The could potentially be a cause in a couple of cases but another site having this issue is on a single domain. We have a site with a similar setup although it's multi-site rather than separate instances. I.e. shop.com for retail and trade.shop.com for trade. 99.9% of the time there's no issue but occasionally someone gets this error on login and no amount of resetting passwords fixes it.